# Session Timeout in plain jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I write sessionTimeOut functionality in plain jQuery without using any pluging? I want to use my own alert ui.To figure out any UI activity I can write but not sure how to combine it in a timeout functionality.

```
$('*').on('click', function () {
    console.log('click', this);

});

$('*').on('change', function() {
    console.log('change', this);
});
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you'd like to reinvent the wheel? There are plenty of high quality session timeout jQuery plugins out there.

Comment: It won't work for elements that are added to a page dynamically. Don't even mention it would add **a lot** of handlers to the DOM

Comment: You could just take a look at the source of existing solutions, and re-write them to fit your own needs, I guess.. If you like to reinvent wheels and stuff..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could on all modern browsers capture mousemove event:

```
(function () {
    var timeoutSession;
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutSession);
        timeoutSession = setTimeout(function () {
            alert('Make SESSION expire');
            //call a script here to server...
        }, 30000); //30s
    }, true);
})();
```

Comment: isn't mousemove going to be a bit excessive? Otherwise a good solution!

Comment: @musefan for sure it is excessive solution but the only one i can think which will be completly relevant. Using click could be better as anyway we don't care if propagation has been stopped or not.

Comment: Worked absolutely fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on roasted's answer, but using ajax calls as your timer reset action instead of mousemoves:

```
(function (delay) {

    function getTimeout() {
        return setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('Make SESSION expire');
            //call a script here to server...
        }, delay);
    };

    // start the session timer
    var timeoutSession = getTimeout();

    $(document).ajaxSend(function() {
        // this event fires any time an ajax call is sent
        console.log('timeout reset');
        clearTimeout(timeoutSession);
        timeoutSession = getTimeout();
    });
})(30000); // <--- notice that you put the timeout delay here
```